# DOM Help (displaying an unordered list of fruits and giving each fruit a class)

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have a variable with a list of fruits as shown below:

```
var fruits = [
"Apple",
"Banana",
"Grape",
"Pineapple",
"Pear"
 ];
```

Using DOM, I want to display an unordered list of the fruits and then give each of the fruits a class of "fruity".

I'm still very uncomfortable with DOM but this is what I have attempted:

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
var unorderedList = document.createElement('ul');
appendChild(ul);
}

for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
var class = document.createElement('class', 'fruity');
appendChild(class);
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm at least on the right track? What I excluded? Am I using "document.createElement" where it's needed? I am totally stuck =/ Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

You want to create **one** `ul` element and then multiple `li` elements. `class` is not an *element*, it's an attribute; you can set the `class` of an element by using its `className` reflected property (for historical reasons, the reflected property isn't just called `class`).

So:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = fruit; // For instance, just to give us something to see
    li.className = "fruity";
    ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

...then append `ul` somewhere, e.g.:

```
document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

...or similar.

**Live Example:**

```js
var fruits = [
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
  "Grape",
  "Pineapple",
  "Pear"
];

var ul = document.createElement('ul');
fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = fruit; // For instance, just to give us something to see
  li.className = "fruity";
  ul.appendChild(li);
});


document.body.appendChild(ul);
```

```css
.fruity {
  color: purple;
}
```

*(They're purple because of the class `fruity`.)*

More on the DOM: http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR

Answer (score 0):

You've taken a detour from the right track ;)

```
var unorderedList = document.createElement("ul");

 fruits.forEach(function (fruit) {
     var listElement = document.createElement("li");
     var listText = document.createTextNode(fruit);
     listElement.appendChild(listText);
     listElement.className = "fruity";
     unorderedList.append(listElement);
 }

 // assuming you have an element with id = "fruits" in your html 
 document.getElementById("fruits").appendChild(unorderedList);
```

Comment: you may also want to assign an ID to the UL using setAttribute

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the `className` and `innerHTML`  on the same loop, i.e.:

```js
var fruits = [
"Apple",
"Banana",
"Grape",
"Pineapple",
"Pear"
 ];
var myElement = document.getElementById("myFruits");
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
var unorderedList = document.createElement('li');
unorderedList.innerHTML = fruits[i];
unorderedList.className = fruits[i];
myElement.appendChild(unorderedList);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myFruits"></ul>
```

---

The above `js` will regenerate the following `html`

```
<ul id="myFruits">
<li class="Apple">Apple</li>
<li class="Banana">Banana</li>
<li class="Grape">Grape</li>
<li class="Pineapple">Pineapple</li>
<li class="Pear">Pear</li>
</ul>
```